# How to deserialize data from multiple sources for one model using DRF?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am transitioning some data over to use DRF.  I have a POST endpoint that takes a JSON payload, parses relevant fields, and creates multiple objects out of that data.  Each subsequent object created also relies on the previous object created (see example below).  I am trying to figure out how to accomplish below, using DRF to deserialize data.  It doesn't exactly have to be modeled like the code below, but I need the same end result.

```
def job_start(request, plat_name="other", script_version="1"):
    a_product, created = Product.objects.get_or_create(name="Mobile")
    a_platform, created = Platform.objects.get_or_create(name=plat_name)
    tool, created = Tool.objects.get_or_create(
                                         product=a_product,
                                         platform=a_platform,
                                         url=jenkins_dump.url)

    job, created = Job.objects.get_or_create(name=jenkins_dump.job_name, tool=tool)
    job_in_progress, _ = Status.objects.get_or_create(name="IN_PROGRESS")
    start_time_raw = datetime.fromtimestamp(jenkins_dump.start_time / 1000)
    job_execution = JobExecution.objects.create(build_id=jenkins_dump.execution_number,
                                                        job=job,
                                                        time_start=start_time_raw,
                                                        status=job_in_progress,
                                                        pipeline_script_version=script_version)


# what I want to do 

    # serializer = ProductSerializer(request.data)
    # if serializer.is_valid():
    #     serializer.save()

    # serializer = ToolSerializer(request.data)
    # if serializer.is_valid():
    #     serializer.save()
```

I'm wondering how I can serialize all these values and then when I create an object, append it to the serialized data, then pass that serialized data to the next object serializer, etc.

Comment: It might help a bit if you showed what the product serializer and toolserializer look like, otherwise I'm a bit confused how they are saving the same data twice. It might be better to override the create/update methods on one serializer to create 2 or more objects.

Comment: yes, I have found that for most real world applications, you're going to just have to override a lot of the create update methods, because often you are passing in multiple objects or handling logic that happens immediately after creating an object, for instance. This would include triggering a push notification or sending an email, or logging something, etc.  The generic views are great and very well architected, but for newbies it's almost like a secret code because it's so concise that everything is implied.  It's too much magic!